# How can I display json to html using node-json2html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I'm trying to display a more complex json output into html and I haven't been able to figure out how the transform should be constructed using [node-json2html](https://github.com/moappi/node-json2html)

My json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "flight.LOL123 ",
    "columns": [
      "time",
      "sequence_number",
      "vert_rate",
      "messages",
      "squawk",
      "altitude",
      "lat",
      "lon",
      "validposition",
      "track",
      "validtrack",
      "speed",
      "seen",
      "hex"
    ],
    "points": [
      [
        1434558860921,
        98792710001,
        -512,
        1018,
        "4543",
        3325,
        15.74181,
        71.60743,
        1,
        290,
        1,
        207,
        0,
        "4692d4"
      ],
      [
        1434558000838,
        98401040001,
        0,
        4,
        "0000",
        25550,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        "4692d4"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I was able to get this:

```
var transform = {'tag':'li','html':'${name}, ${points}'};
```

but it will produce a first line containing the name and then the points are all on a single, long line.

Can anyone help me try to get the transformation right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another faster and pretty solution by using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

This code is for my original JSON:

```
            {{#.}}

            <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Data for {{name}}</h2></div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>

            <table  class="table table-striped">
            {{#columns}}
                <th>{{.}}</th>
            {{/columns}}

            {{#points}}
                <tr>
                  {{#.}}
                     <td>{{.}}</td>
                  {{/.}}
                </tr>
            {{/points}}

            {{/.}}
            </table>

            </div>
```

With only these I'm populating tables of >5k lines in a heart beat. Pretty cool stuff!

Answer (score 1):

For what I see, you use quite different formatting compared from the example of the library you mention.

Once again the official example format:

```
 var data = [{'male':'Bob','female':'Jane'},{'male':'Rick','female':'Ann'}];
```

Your formatting is nested, not flat as it should be.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dejan!
Unfortunately I cannot change the formatting, can I still somehow display it a bit more readable in HTML?

Comment: Why you don't pass the object to Jade and render it within the jade file?

Comment: Had no idea that Jade can do this for me, everywhere I've searched the node-json2html came back; thank you!

Comment: Even better- use jspath(NPM) to make any fancy filtering and then you pass to Jade much simplified data. This in case you can't make Jade work with your object.